# SharePoint online, add custom ribbon button (or export list to txt)

Tags: 2013

We use SharePoint 2013 Online, so not on premise. I want to export a list to a txt file with fixed column width. Out of the box this is not possible, but in C# it is 'rather' easy.

I'm looking for a way to add a custom ribbon button/action with some C# code behind it that will export my list to a .txt file.

I cannot use Visual Studio -> cannot create new empty SharePoint project because it is SharePoint Online.

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Office 365 or SharePoint Online Dedicated (SPO-D)?